# One tab's data is being duplicated into other tabs

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating JQuery tabs, but I find that one's data ( in this case iframe ) is being duplicated in all tabs. The html looks like this

```
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#room_booking">Make A Booking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#info"> Your Information </a></li>
            <li><a href="#edit_pro"> Edit Your Information </a></li>

        </ul>

        <div id="room_booking">

            <iframe src="/booking/"> </iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="info">

            <fieldset>

                <label>Name : </label><input class="box" type="text" value="{{ userprofile.first_name}} {{userprofile.last_name }}" readonly="" /> <br />
                <label>E-Mail: </label><input class="box" type="text" value="{{ userprofile.email }}" readonly="" /> <br />
                <label>User Name : </label><input class="box" type="text" value="{{ userprofile.username}}" readonly="" /> <br />

            </fieldset>

        </div>

        <div id="#edit_pro">
            <iframe src="/edit/"> </iframe>
        </div>

    </div>
```

My .js file just has

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs();
});
```

This is what it looks like - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Xsn54pdmU8bDRYeFZPU1RtQlU/edit?usp=sharing

Any idea what's causing this? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're missing some CSS for hiding inactive tabs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think jQuery UI does that for you, so that the inactive tabs are hidden

Comment: you have # in the id for edit_pro, that'll probably be causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **'#'** from your **edit_pro** div id.

```
  <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#room_booking">Make A Booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#info"> Your Information </a></li>
                <li><a href="#edit_pro"> Edit Your Information </a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="room_booking">
                <iframe src="/booking/"> </iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="info">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Name : </label><input class="box" type="text" value="{{ userprofile.first_name}} {{userprofile.last_name }}" readonly="" /> <br />
                    <label>E-Mail: </label><input class="box" type="text" value="{{ userprofile.email }}" readonly="" /> <br />
                    <label>User Name : </label><input class="box" type="text" value="{{ userprofile.username}}" readonly="" /> <br />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id="edit_pro">
                <iframe src="/edit/"> </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/kX5L2/1/

Comment: jQuery UI should take care of this for you